# How to make a callback to GO method from C++ DLL

Tags: c++, go, dll, cgo

I have a GO program with a function that make a CGO call to c method defined in a dll. That part works great.. 
Now i need to make a callback from my dll to GO. Is that possible, any helping pointers ?

Note that my DLL code is separate codebase which gets compiled and linked separately to generate dll using visual studio. I'm on windows 10 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found exactly what i was looking for. Posting here so that it may help other with this problem.

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#function-pointer-callbacks

Comment: Mark your own answer as accepted -- this is a recommended practice on SO.